# Alert dialog in angularjs causes page scroll to top

Tags: css, angularjs

I want to use an alert dialog in my angularjs application instead of all the `$window.alert` present. In each of the controllers of my application I inserted this (https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog):

```
$scope.showAlert = function(ev) {
 $mdDialog.show(
  $mdDialog.alert()
    .parent(angular.element(document.body))
    .clickOutsideToClose(true)
    .title('This is an alert title')
    .textContent('You can specify some description text in here.')
    .ariaLabel('Alert Dialog Demo')
    .ok('Got it!')
    .targetEvent(ev)
);};
```

and in my style.css file I added this:

```
.md-dialog-is-showing {
    top: 0 !important;
}
```

The problem is that when $scope.showAlert is called the page under the modal dialog srolls on top and when I close the dialog returns to the previous position. How can I prevent the scroll-to-top in order to bring up the dialog at the same position where it is called?

---------- EDITED ----------

I tried to remove the css rule added but the entire web page, including dialog, doesn't appear. I noted that in the body tag the auto-generated style was the following (top: -1505px causes the problem)

```
<body ng-app="configuratorApp" class="ng-scope md-dialog-is-showing" style="position: fixed; width: 100%; top: -1505px; overflow: hidden;">

<md-backdrop class="md-dialog-backdrop md-opaque ng-scope" style="height: 2059px; position: fixed;" aria-hidden="true"></md-backdrop> ...
```

Comment: Seems like the issue is with the css you added. Remove it and try modal again

Comment: I removed a css rule from the body `overflow-x: hidden;` and now it works